# React + antd TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, antd

I'm trying to add the `antd` library to a React project generated from Visual Studio 2017 (15.2.2).

I started from the project template "ASP.NET Core Web Application" and after chose "React.js" in the below window.

[image: screenshot]

At this point everything works fine.

If I add `antd` in `package.json` ("antd": "3.1.0") and I add an import in some `tsx` file, for example `home.tsx` like this:

```
import { Row } from 'antd';
```

I get 3 errors:

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/antd/lib/badge/ScrollNumber.d.ts:28:56 
>           TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'DetailedReactHTMLElement'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/antd/lib/badge/ScrollNumber.d.ts:38:52 
>           TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'DetailedReactHTMLElement'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/antd/lib/input/TextArea.d.ts:15:47 
>           TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'TextareaHTMLAttributes'.

How can I fix these errors?

I have tried to update all packages but I still get the same errors ...
I have some others projects with both React and antd, that are not based on the React.js template provided by Visual Studio 2017, and I don't have any errors.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but using the React Redux template. I edited your question and added a bounty to try and get some help with this.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to solve this is to upgrade your "typescript" package and all your React related packages (includes @types/react-*) except "react-hot-loader" (only upgrade it to latest ^3) to their latest major version.

If you still have problems, delete node_modules, yarn.lock, npm-shrinkwrap.json and wwwroot/dist then retry.

Comment: If you are using `yarn`, you could try this package (that helps me a lot): https://yarnpkg.com/package/yarn-upgrade-all

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `antd` library has a [peer dependency of react >= 16](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/package.json#L38), but, like you said, Visual Studio 2017 generates a repo with react version 15.2.2.

One solution would be to change your `react` (really your `@types/react`, but you should change both) dependency to the latest version, which as of right now is [16.3.2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react). This is what @Zack suggests and would probably be the better solution. Keep in mind that if you're going to upgrade the `react` version number, you should probably also upgrade the `react-dom` version and the `@types/react-dom` version.

Alternatively, if you wanted to keep Visual Studio's output as-is, you could use the last version of `antd` that supports `react` v15, which is `antd` version 2.13.11. To install this, run `npm install antd@2.13.11`. The disadvantage of this is that you wouldn't be able to use any other packages that depend on `react` v16.